# Emacs auto encryption and gpg

Tags: emacs, encryption, gpg

Emacs encrypts/decrypts `.gpg` files automatically. But recently I have lost the ability to decrypt files encrypted by the Linux `gpg` tool and vice versa.

I use:

- passphrase symmetric encryption
- gnupg 1.4.11
- emacs 24.0.92.1
- Debian sid

Decrypting using `gpg` (encrypted by emacs) gives:

```
gpg: decryption failed: bad key
```

Decrypting using emacs (encrypted by gpg) gives:

```
epa-file--find-file-not-found-function: Opening input file: Decryption failed,
```

Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Are you sure `gpg` and `emacs` are using the same key?

Comment: Not enough info about what is happening in your system for the question to be answerable and useful for others.

Comment: I use passphrase for symmetric encription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in [this (in Russian)](http://ru-emacs.livejournal.com/82428.html) solution which manipulates with input method. At present time it affects on passphrase during encryption/decryption.

Comment: Could you explain the issue in your post? Both for the benefit of people who don't speak Russian, and to prepare for the inevitable link rot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I recently had the same problem, so I'll post my solution anyway.

In my case the file was encrypted using a GnuPG key. At one point in a long-lived session, Emacs lost the ability to decrypt the file giving me the same error message as as in the original post:

```
epa-file--find-file-not-found-function: Opening input file: Decryption failed
```

I found that if I killed any related 'gpg-agent' process running in the background, Emacs then regained the ability to decrypt the file (after asking for the passphrase again).

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing a suitable pinentry program and unfortunately Emacs' output is less than helpful.

On a RedHat system your might want try installing the `pinentry-gtk` package and see if everything works.